# react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm currently trying to follow this beginner tutorial for react, linked from the official react page: https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/
and it doesn't work already at the point where I delete the contents of the src directory and create an index.js file with the following content:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Now I get the following error in the browser: Uncaught TypeError: `react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function`

[image]

there's no error in the compilation, so I don't know what I did wrong.